How to overcome Microsoft Authentication Error in Blazor in MacOS?


We're unable to complete your request
invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.

I get the above error when I am trying to log into the webpage I am developing using C#.Net. I am using a MacBook with M2 chip. I used an Outlook e-mail address to log into the system.
